# Xamarin Forms OAuth2 Microsoft/Google authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms, forms-authentication

I'm building an app that should be able to send emails. I'm using OAuth2 to verify the user, and I've looked at the [Xamarin Forms Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/) which works great with gmail after setup.
However it doesn't work with my Microsoft account.

I've created a cliendId and all that stuff on Microsoft. Do I have to have a Azure AD as well?

I'm calling the authentication with:

```
new OAuth2Authenticator(
                "myClientId",
                "User.Read",
                new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=myid&scope=user.read&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"),
                new Uri("myRedirectUri"),
                null,
                true);
```

But am reaching a screen saying: We cannot perform your request.
Microsoft-accounts is having technical issues right now. Try again later.

Have looked at [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Auth-Login-Authenticating-ef41cf0c) sample, where the author uses Google and Microsoft accounts in similar ways.

If I'm instead using [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2) sample it works with the original setup, but not if I change to my own clientId and redirectUrl. Is this since I don't have any Azure account?
Would not like to pay to get it, and since the first approach works fine with my gmail I would love if it could work with Microsoft as well.

/Oliver

Comment: Do you register your app? It is necessary to get redirectUri and more. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-app-registration "For mobile apps, copy down the default redirect uri automatically created for you." You don't need Azure AD account if you have Microsoft account. It says "At least one of the following accounts:
A Microsoft Account
An Azure AD account"

Comment: Yes I've registered my app. Have been using the customized redirect uri, not the built in, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you know if I did it all right with the scope and the authorized url?

Comment: how can I know if you did it right?

Comment: Thought maybe you have been working with OAuth2 and recognized the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the microsoftonline.com endpoints instead? I've also implemented this using Xamarin.Auth and could get it working that way.

- AuthorizeUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- AccessTokenUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

"common" is the {tenant} which you can replace with "consumers" if you only wanna allow personal accounts.

Comment: Thanks will try this right away! What scope are you using? And how do you use the redirect url?

Comment: I'm using `openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read` as scope.
Regarding the redirect url, this is currently configured as `msal{ApplicationId}://auth/oauth2redirect` where {ApplicationId} is the application id including dashes.
In your `AuthUrlInterceptorActivity` you need to extend the `DataSchemes` and `DataPaths` properties of the `IntentFilterAttribute` accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting an error, saying that the webpage can't be reached when trying to reach the redirect url

Comment: which part of the `Redirect url` do I put as `DataSchemes` and as `DataPaths` ? And how do I choose which `AuthUrlInterceptorActivity` to be used, since I'm guessing I need one for Google and one for Microsoft, or at least change the `DataSchemes` and the `DataPaths`

Comment: if you're getting an error about the redirect url in the browser component then you should check whatever you've entered at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. Once this is configured correctly you shouldn't get any errors anymore in the browser component regardless whether or not your xamarin app is configured correctly.

Comment: Regarding the configuration of the Xamarin.Android app, one AuthUrlInterceptorActivity should certainly be sufficient. DataPaths and DataSchemes are both arrays. If you use a redirect url similar to the one mentioned in my previous comment, put the part in front of the : into DataSchemes. However, I really recommend you to do this step by step and focus on that in-browser error message first (see comment above)

Comment: I've checked at apps.dev.microsoft.com, at first I only had `msal{ApplicationId}://auth` which was created by itself, then after your advice I added an extra redirect url, with `/oauth2redirect` at the end, but I still get the same error, with the error code: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Somehow it worked when having the proper `DataScheme` and `DataPath`, how would you choose which one to use, depending on google or microsoft?

Comment: How do I after authentication get information about the user, like email or profile. Guessing I need these as scope, but what do I use like `UserInfoUrl` when doing a GET request?

Comment: Once again, DataSchemes and DataPaths are arrays. So you can simply add both, the values for Google AND the ones for MS. Regarding user info, you can either decode the id_token or call into the corresponding userinfo endpoint. For the latter, simply use OAuth2Request instead of HttpRequest.

Comment: Oh didn't think about that, thanks!

Tried getting the email through id_token, but I had problem decoding it from json.

I'm doing it with a OAuth2Request, but that still requires a url.

Comment: Otherwise Authentication with OAuth2 works fint, but then when I'm trying to Authenticate to SMTP server through Mailkit, I get an AuthenticationError: `authentication failed authenthicationInvalidCredentials 5.0.0` Works fine with google but not with MS

Comment: and regarding mailkit, I'm not sure whether microsoft's smtp server actually supports this. alternatively you can use the correspoinding mail api https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail or use an android intent to simply open a prepopulated email compose dialog. The second approach might raise less concerns with your user-base than asking them for permission to send emails in their name.
please try to google your new questions fist and if necessary open new questions for these new topics.

Comment: No Accepted answer? I am getting error as "`invalid_grant`" and "`invalid_request`" with microsoft account using xamarin.auth. MSDN saying pass `grant_type:authorization_code` but this is not available in xamarin.auth. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to coding it yourself, is to use a 3rd party library to handle authentication.

[CloudRail](https://cloudrail.com) have SDKs for Xamarin, with build-in integrations for social login/authentication, and also for email sending, which you mention.